# How to graph only an arc section from a full circle?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

How to constrain the standard formula of a circle that has the form of $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ in such a way that only an arc section is visible.

I was thinking about using the coordinates of two points on the circumference of the circle as restriction points.

By the way, I am using Desmos as a graphing calculator.

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly or not. If I do, what you can do is write the cycle using polar coordinates. Then, restrict the angle, say $\pi/6 \le \theta \le \pi/3$

Comment: @ALNS How would you graph that in Desmos (a graphing calculator)?

Comment: Use $r=1+0*\theta$, and it will prompt you for entering a theta range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using Desmos, here's an [example](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uaaij4jqlc) of what you want.

`(x - 2)^2 + (y + 1)^2 = 4 {pi/4 < arctan(x - 2, y + 1) < 3pi/4}`

[image]

The general expression you need is

`(x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2 = R^2 {a1 < arctan(x - h, y - k) < a2}`

- `(h, k)` is the center of the circle
- `R` is the radius
- `a1` and `a2`, where $-\pi<a_1<a_2\le\pi$, determine the measure of the arc and its endpoints
- `arctan(x, y)` denotes the [two-argument arctan function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) whose output is a real number between $-\pi$ and $\pi$
- `{ ... }` denotes a condition placed on the preceding expression, e.g. `y = x^2 {x > 0}` would plot only the right half of the parabola $y=x^2$.

Alternatively, Desmos recognizes `r = <function of theta>` as a function in polar coordinates, so one could also get away with e.g.

`r = 1 {pi/4 < theta < 3pi/4}`

More generally, let $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$. Substituting these into the Cartesian equation for the circle, we get

$$\left(r\cos(\theta)-h\right)^2 + \left(r\sin(\theta) - k\right)^2 = R^2 \\
\implies r^2 - 2r(h\cos(\theta) + k\sin(\theta)) = R^2 - h^2 - k^2 \\
\implies r = (h\cos(\theta)+k\sin(\theta)) \pm \sqrt{R^2 - h^2 - k^2 + (h\cos(\theta)+k\sin(\theta))^2}$$

[Here is a plot in polar](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fo2e4mkfgr) of two "halves" of the same circle used earlier. One can also impose a condition with the `{ ... }` syntax to plot only part of either arc. Note that the overall domain (one branch of it, anyway) for the circle is $-\frac\pi2<\theta<2\arctan\left(\frac13\right)$, courtesy of the square root.

[image]